# what is the meaning of $ in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular 2 with Typescript .
I came across an example which has quite confused me . Here it goes

In

**component.ts**

```
getValidation(state:any, thingName?: string) {  
  let thing: string = state.path || thingName;   
  let messages : string[] = [];   
  messages.push(`You must enter a **${thing}**`);    
}
```

What is the significance of using `$` and `{}` in the above example, until now I always used **this.thing** to use any variable?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: this is string interpolation its also seen is JS ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're referring to our [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in **JavaScript** (TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript*). It's a way to refer to variable defined outside of everything you have defined within the backticks.  So `${variable}` is simply the way to reference it is all.